# Console CP can't be change when I use unit Crt in Pascal

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal

I made a simple program by Pascal to show unicode string to console screen.

I use **SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)** and it work normally.

But when I add CRT unit to my program, it have an problem: Console codepage can not change.

I was try to use

```
Swapvectors;
Exec('Cmd','/c chcp 65001');
Swapvectors;
```

And

```
{$Codepage UTF8}
```

But it also have an error. Please give me a solutions for this problem. Thanks.

(I'm using Lazarus IDE)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is: You can't.

Unit Crt is an old DOS remnant that was invented before multi-byte character sets or UTF-8. The introductory page of the manual says the following:

> The CRT unit stems from the TP/Dos area. It is designed to work with single-byte character sets, where 1 char = 1 byte. That means that widestrings or **UTF-8 encoded (ansi)strings** will not correctly work.

(Highlights mine)